# VBA find same cell values, count and calculate

Tags: vba

I want to count all the same values ​​in column C and calculate something from the number of the same values ​​* 10 / the associated B value of the cells.

example

If C3, C6 and C8 are the same then

Number of same values ​​-> (3) * 10 / (B3*B6*B8)/4

So far I've only found one way to compare the whole thing.

```
Sub Check()

Dim CRange As Range
Dim myValue
Dim allSame As Boolean

Set CRange = Range("C1:C30")

myValue = CRange(1, 1).Value

allSame = (WorksheetFunction.CountA(CRange) = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CRange, myValue))
MsgBox allSame
```

End Sub

Comment: Do you need to calculate a specific value, or all cells value in the range?

Comment: All cells with the same value in range

Comment: I meant, do you want returning a result for `myValue` variable, or for all cells? If for all cells, where the result to be returned?

Comment: I answered you below, it worked better with the table

Comment: Not sure I could understand what you say... I will post an answer able to return for your specific question

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following?

```
Dim RunningTotal , NumberCells, MyValue as Integer
MyValue = sheets(1).range("C1").value
For i = 2 to 30
    If (sheets(1).range("C" & i).value=MyValue)
    Then
        RunningTotal = RunningTotal + (sheets(1).range("B"&I).value
        NumberCells = NumberCells + 1
    End if
End for
MsgBox(RunningTotal & " : " & NumberCells)
```

The final calcule is not clearly explained but this retrieves the values needed to find it.

Comment: Did you test the above code? It still creates a range in a wrong way (even after editing) and it misses `Then`. Besides that, its logic misses the requirement about values in the previous column, too.

Comment: Thank you @FaneDaru - I've added the "Then" . No : I haven't tested it. I don't have access to a machine with Excel today. The request was to look for the value in C find the total of the values in the same rows in B and the calculate. I've retrieved the 2 figures to calculate the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next way:

```
Sub testEvaluateFormula()
  Dim CRange  As Range, myValue As Range, allSame As Double
  
  Set CRange = Range("C1:C30")
  Set myValue = CRange(1, 1)

  allSame = Evaluate("=COUNTIF(" & CRange.Address & "," & myValue.Address & ")*10/(SUMIF(" & _
                  CRange.Address & "," & myValue.Address & "," & CRange.Offset(0, -1).Address & ")/4)")
  MsgBox "allSame = " & allSame
End Sub
```

The above code can be easily adapted to return for any two used ranges. I can even transform it in a function...

**Edited**:

Please, use the next function:

```
Function makeCalculation(CRange As Range, myVal As Range) As Double
     makeCalculation = Evaluate("=COUNTIF(" & CRange.Address & "," & myVal.Address & ")*10/(SUMIF(" & _
                        CRange.Address & "," & myVal.Address & "," & CRange.Offset(0, -1).Address & ")/4)")
End Function
```

It can be called as:

```
Sub testAllSame()
  Dim CRange  As Range, myValue As Range, allSame As Double
  
  Set CRange = Range("C1:C30")
  Set myValue = CRange(1, 1)
  allSame = makeCalculation(CRange, myValue)
 
  MsgBox "allSame = " & allSame
End Sub
```

You can call the function for any `CRange` and `myValue` range. It will return on the same logic: Counting the in `CRange` the `myValue` value occurrences, multiplies them with 10 and divides the result at `SumIf` for the column before `CRange` divided by 4.

Comment: Sry but it dont works give me a sec. i test it again

Comment: @AeQ Dansen What does "it dont works" mean? Does it return an error? If so, what error on which line? If not, **did you  test the code exactly as it is**, including variables declaration?

Comment: It works ty perfect

Comment: @AeQ Dansen Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the solution works.